# Convert .csv file to ZIP file using Powershell and store in Azure blob stroage

Tags: azure, powershell, storage, runbook

I am trying to convert .CSV file to .ZIP using Powershell and then store the ZIP file in Azure blob storage.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SvrName -Database $dataname -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Query $getTABLEdetails | Export-CSV $filename1 -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

With the above command I am storing the output in .CSV file. Now I want to convert the .CSV file .ZIP file. And store the ZIP file in Azure blob storage.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'Accountname' -StorageAccountKey 'storagekey'
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container zipfiles -File $filename1 -Blob $filename1 -Context $context -Force
```

With the above command I can store it in .CSV file. But I want to store the file in .ZIP format.

Is their any way I can achieve this?

Please help

Comment: You can use [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.1).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7) to place your CSV file in a ZIP archive file before uploading to Blob storage.

To extract the filename from the CSV file, I use `-LeafBase` from [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7), then format this filename into a ZIP file path using the [`Format operator -f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#format-operator--f). Could also just concatenate with `(Split-Path -Path $csvFile -LeafBase) + '.zip'`.

```
$storageAccountName = 'Accountname'
$storageAccountKey = 'storagekey'
$containerName = 'zipfiles'

$csvFile = 'data.csv'

# Format into data.zip
$zipFile = '{0}.zip' -f (Split-Path -Path $csvFile -LeafBase)

# Create archive file
# Use -Update to overwrite if necessary
Compress-Archive -Path $csvFile -DestinationPath $zipFile -Update

# Get current storage account context
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

# Upload .zip file to Blob storage container
# Use -Force to skip prompts
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $containerName -Blob $zipFile -File $zipFile -Context $context -Force
```

To use the newer Az modules, we can replace `New-AzureStorageContext` with `New-AzStorageContext` and `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` with `Set-AzStorageBlobContent`.